# How to execute Column expression in spark without dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Is there any way that I can evaluate my `Column` expression if I am only using `Literal` (no dataframe columns).

For example, something like:

```scala
val result: Int = someFunction(lit(3) * lit(5))
//result: Int = 15
```

or

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.function.sha1
val result: String = someFunction(sha1(lit("5")))
//result: String = ac3478d69a3c81fa62e60f5c3696165a4e5e6ac4
```

I am able to evaluate using a dataframes

```scala
val result = Seq(1).toDF.select(sha1(lit("5"))).as[String].first
//result: String = ac3478d69a3c81fa62e60f5c3696165a4e5e6ac4
```

But is there any way to get the same results without using dataframe?

Comment: Just curious, why do you need this? Also I tried your approach and it does not trigger any spark job. Therefore could you tell us what's wrong with the approach you propose?

Comment: There are so many use cases like to test your custom UDF's, to test your complex column expressions and to reuse existing functions from `sql.function._` in your custom UDF's.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To evaluate a literal column you can [convert it](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Column@expr:org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Expression) to an [`Expression`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/a381bce7285ec30f58f28f523dfcfe0c13221bbf/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/expressions/Expression.scala#L56) and [`eval`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/a381bce7285ec30f58f28f523dfcfe0c13221bbf/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/expressions/Expression.scala#L91) without providing `input` row:

```scala
scala> sha1(lit("1").cast("binary")).expr.eval()
res1: Any = 356a192b7913b04c54574d18c28d46e6395428ab
```

As long as the function is an `UserDefinedFunction` it will work the same way:

```scala
scala> val f = udf((x: Int) => x)
f: org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.UserDefinedFunction = UserDefinedFunction(<function1>,IntegerType,Some(List(IntegerType)))

scala> f(lit(3) * lit(5)).expr.eval()
res3: Any = 15
```

Comment: Very cool stuff! Do you know how to make it work with string expressions? `expr("sha1(CAST(1 AS BINARY))").expr.eval()` fails with "java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Cannot evaluate expression: 'sha1(cast(1 as binary))"

Answer (score -2):

The following code can help:

```
val isUuid = udf((uuid: String) => uuid.matches("[a-fA-F0-9]{8}-[a-fA-F0-9]{4}-[a-fA-F0-9]{4}-[a-fA-F0-9]{4}-[a-fA-F0-9]{12}"))


df.withColumn("myCol_is_uuid",isUuid(col("myCol")))
.filter("myCol_is_uuid = true")
.show(10, false)
```