# Error using python built in function **abs** in pyspark-2.3

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I was trying to convert negative number to positive by using python built in **abs** function in pyspark shell-2.3.

```
numb = -2
print(abs(numb))
```

Its throwing me a weird error:

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.sql.functions.abs. Trace:
**py4j.Py4JException: Method abs([class java.lang.Integer]) does not exist
    at**
py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:318)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:339)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:276)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

could you please help me ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not how you use [`pyspark.sql.functions`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#module-pyspark.sql.functions). There are not designed to be evaluated outside [`DataFrame`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.2/sql-programming-guide.html#untyped-dataset-operations-aka-dataframe-operations) context, and operate on [`Columns`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=column#pyspark.sql.Column).

You could use literal `Column`:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import abs, lit 

abs(lit(numb))
```

but it'll give you yet another [`Column`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=column#pyspark.sql.Column):

```
Column<b'abs(-2)'>
```

While in theory such objects [can be evaluated locally](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51210178/10939067), it is not intended for public usage.

If you want to operate on plain Python numerics just stick to [Python's built-in `abs`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#abs).

If you've shaded built-in functions you can express the function from the comments as:

```
def math_result(current_val, value): 
    result = ((value - current_val) / value)  *100 
    return __builtins__.abs(__builtins__.round(result, 2)) 

math_result(1, 3)                                            
## 66.67
```

Answer (score 0):

Python has built-in abs method.

pyspark also provides abs method but that is for DataFrame column.

If you do import pyspark method 'abs' in pyspark shell then you do override built-in abs method.

It looks like you have override abs method something like below:

```
>>> print(abs(-3))
3
>>> from pyspark.sql.functions import abs
>>> print(abs(-3))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/rs301t/spark-2.3.2-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/sql/functions.py", line 42, in _
    jc = getattr(sc._jvm.functions, name)(col._jc if isinstance(col, Column) else col)
  File "/Users/rs301t/spark-2.3.2-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1257, in __call__
  File "/Users/rs301t/spark-2.3.2-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "/Users/rs301t/spark-2.3.2-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 332, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.sql.functions.abs. Trace:
py4j.Py4JException: Method abs([class java.lang.Integer]) does not exist
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:318)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:339)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:276)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

We should avoid import functions name directly and try to use alias for module so can call right method which we intended.